# Is it possible to add an user avatar icon for Git for Windows (off a Windows network drive share)

Tags: windows, git

I'm running Git for Windows off a Windows network drive share (using just basic Active Directory permissions to access Git).  Is it possible to add a user Avatar icon via git command-line.. similar to how you define a username and email?

Comment: Git doesn't support avatars, are you talking about Git*Hub*?

Comment: Thanks.  I think that might be the case.  I'm using the VSCode Gitlens plugin.. Which isn't specific to Github.. However, when when I use it with Github, I can see my Github avatar.  When I use it against a regular Git install, I get a generic icon.

Comment: Github is fetching avatars from https://en.gravatar.com/. I don't know if it's part of the solution.